# Initializing ldap...failed. (28416)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, linode, zimbra

I am trying to configure Zimbra on my Linode (ubuntu). It's been more than 12 continuous hours but I am unable to get it configured correctly. I have followed too many guides from internet already. For the last try, I was trying this: [Configure Zimbra](http://www.mmj-ict.com/zimbra-os-edition-8-5/) and as usual the same error occured. This is the error:

```
Installing Proxy SSL certificate...done.
Initializing ldap...failed. (28416)


ERROR



Configuration failed

Please address the error and re-run /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl to
complete the configuration.

Errors have been logged to /tmp/zmsetup05102015-071817.log
```

And this is the last few lines of log file:

```
Sun May 10 07:22:20 2015 done.
Sun May 10 07:22:20 2015 Installing LDAP SSL certificate...
Sun May 10 07:22:20 2015 *** Running as root user: /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr deploycrt self
** Saving server config key zimbraSSLCertificate...failed.
** Saving server config key zimbraSSLPrivateKey...failed.
** Installing mta certificate and key...done.
** Installing slapd certificate and key...done.
** Installing proxy certificate and key...done.
** Creating pkcs12 file /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/jetty.pkcs12...done.
** Creating keystore file /opt/zimbra/mailboxd/etc/keystore...done.
** Installing CA to /opt/zimbra/conf/ca...done.
Sun May 10 07:22:25 2015 done.
Sun May 10 07:22:25 2015 Installing Proxy SSL certificate...
Sun May 10 07:22:25 2015 *** Running as root user: /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr deploycrt self
** Saving server config key zimbraSSLCertificate...failed.
** Saving server config key zimbraSSLPrivateKey...failed.
** Installing mta certificate and key...done.
** Installing slapd certificate and key...done.
** Installing proxy certificate and key...done.
** Creating pkcs12 file /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/jetty.pkcs12...done.
** Creating keystore file /opt/zimbra/mailboxd/etc/keystore...done.
** Installing CA to /opt/zimbra/conf/ca...done.
Sun May 10 07:22:30 2015 done.
Sun May 10 07:22:30 2015 checking isEnabled zimbra-ldap
Sun May 10 07:22:30 2015 zimbra-ldap is enabled
Sun May 10 07:22:30 2015 Initializing ldap...
Sun May 10 07:22:30 2015 *** Running as zimbra user: /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmldapinit
Connection refused at /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmldapinit line 138.
Sun May 10 07:23:13 2015 failed. (28416)
Sun May 10 07:23:13 2015

ERROR
```

I am not sure, what can be wrong or how to fix it. If any of you have ever faced such problem and know the solution, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by checking the /tmp/zmsetup05102015-071817.log and then do you have any services that could prevent ldap starting? moreover any ports that may already be in use preventing this?