# Troubles installing Zimbra 8.6 on AZURE VM (Ubuntu 14.04 Server)

Tags: azure, dns, ldap, zimbra, dnsmasq

I have troubles installing Zimbra 8.6 on AZURE VM (Ubuntu 14.04 Server). Before the final configuration complete, I got this error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
***** CONFIGURATION COMPLETE - press 'a' to apply

Select from menu, or press 'a' to apply config (? - help) a

Save configuration data to a file? [Yes] yes

Save config in file: [/opt/zimbra/config.9228]

Saving config in /opt/zimbra/config.9228...done.

The system will be modified - continue? [No] yes

Operations logged to /tmp/zmsetup.0331224312-204237.log

Setting local config values...done.

Setting up CA...done.

Deploying CA to /opt/zimbra/conf/ca ...done.

Creating SSL certificate...done.

Installing mailboxd SSL certificates...done.

**Initializing ldap...failed. (28416)**


**ERROR**



**Configuration failed**

**Please address the error and re-run /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl to
complete the configuration.**

Errors have been logged to /tmp/zmsetup.0331224312-204237.log
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does it say in `/tmp/zmsetup.0331224312-204237.log`? What command(s) did you use to initiate this configuration script? Have you done [any research on the error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=zimbra+Initializing+ldap...failed)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing ldap...failed. (28416)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148847/initializing-ldap-failed-28416)